# Wordpress get_option checked do something

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Hi I am wanting to test result of a checkbox in wordpress being true or false

```
  if(checked(1, get_option('demo-checkbox'), true)){?>
      //do something...
  <?php } ?>
```

However on front end I am getting unexpected results and its outputting `checked='checked'` in the html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was quite easy

```
  if (get_option('demo-checkbox') === '1') {?>
```

Thanks